# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:: column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, hibernate, rest, jpa, spring-boot

I have bidirectional OneToMany-manyToOne relationship in my tables and i am getting *MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'hospital_id' cannot be null.*

Could you help me with that? I spent 3 hours on this...

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hospital_doctor")
@IdClass(HospitalDoctor.class)
public class HospitalDoctor implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private Doctor doctor;
private Hospital hospital;

@Id
private int id;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date contract_start_date;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date contract_end_date;
private String position;
private String supervisor;
private boolean part_time;



public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Id
@ManyToOne
@JsonManagedReference
@JoinColumn(name="doctor_id")
public Doctor getDoctor() {
    return doctor;
}
public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
    this.doctor = doctor;
}


@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="hospital_id")
public Hospital getHospital() {
    return hospital;
}
public void setHospital(Hospital hospital) {
    this.hospital = hospital;
} 

 /**GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

AND MODEL CLASSES:

```
@Entity

public class Hospital {

    private Set<HospitalDoctor> hospitalDoctors;


@Column
int Id;
@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
String name;
@Column
String country;
@Column
String town;
@Column
String street;
@Column
String postal_code;
@Column
String phone_number;
@Column
String fax_number;
@Column
int number_of_ambulances;
@Column
boolean helicopter_access;
@Column
boolean teaching_hospital;





@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="doctor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<HospitalDoctor> getHospitalDoctors() {
    return hospitalDoctors;
}


public void setHospitalDoctors(Set<HospitalDoctor> hospitalDoctors) {
    this.hospitalDoctors = hospitalDoctors;
}


@Id
public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}
  //Rest of getters and setters
```

And last one:

```
   @Entity
public class Doctor {

    private Set<HospitalDoctor> hospitalDoctors;




@Column(name = "Id")
int id;

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
String surname;

@Column(name = "title")
String title;

@Column(name = "license_number", unique = true)
int license_number;

@Column(name = "phone")
String phone;

@Column(name = "email")
String email;

@Column(name = "nationality")
String nationality;

@Column(name = "speciality")
String speciality;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
Date date_of_birth;

@Column(name = "is_a_teacher")
boolean is_a_teacher;

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="doctor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<HospitalDoctor> getHospitalDoctors() {
    return hospitalDoctors;
}



public void setHospitalDoctors(Set<HospitalDoctor> hospitalDoctors) {
    this.hospitalDoctors = hospitalDoctors;
}

@Id
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

My service method (using JpaRepository)

```
    public void addHospitalDoctor(HospitalDoctor hospitalDoctor) {
    hospitalDoctorDao.save(hospitalDoctor);
}
```

And RestController

```
@PostMapping(value="/api/hospitaldoctors")
public void addHospitalDoctor(HospitalDoctor hospitalDoctor){
    hospitalDoctorService.addHospitalDoctor(hospitalDoctor);
}
```

If anyOne could help me with that I'll be very glad. Cheers :)

Comment: An entity cannot be its own `@IdClass`. That is for where you want to define a specific PK class. If you only have 1 `@Id` field then it is not needed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I should create HospitalDoctorsId class which contains Id?

Comment: You cannot annotate some FIELDS and some GETTERS; pick one or the other. Then, if your really have to have a composite PK (not best practice) you need to define an `IdClass`.